# regex validator in primefaces

Tags: regex, primefaces

```
 <p:inputText id="username" value="#{personBean.username}" required="true" label="username">  
                <f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$%]))" />
 </p:inputText>
```

The above regex pattern is required with at least one digit, one letter and one special symbol (“@#$%”).

the error message is displayed when the input is not of the correct pattern and the error is displayed even when the input is in correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex-pattern instead:

```
(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[A-z])(?=.*?[@#$%])+
```

First of all you missed a part for upper case characters and then you missed the `+` at the end, so it would only validate if you have one character and if this character is of one of the specified types.

Comment: see the edited part of my ques."(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[@#$%])+" this regex doesnt work as well

Comment: see the edited part of my ques."(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[@#$%])+" this regex doesnt work as well. it can be any type of letter(capital or small). but the above regex should have atleast one number, one small alphabet and a special character. the error im getting on typing "admin@1" i get "regex not matched".

Comment: I updated my answer, at first you said you would like to have at least one upper case character too, so it was my answer on the initial question...

Comment: what would be regex for the ques i edited. pattern with at least one digit, one letter and one special symbol (“@#$%”).

Comment: I already updated the answer for your new requirements, please check if it works.

Comment: the regex pattern you have posted should accept atleast one number, one upper case letter and one special symbol, right?. the input i gave was admin@1A. still it says regex pattern not matched.